# Left outer join returns results in both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, sql-server-2014-express

Join returns value, but value is found in both tables. Is my syntax bad?

```
    select distinct source.[Manufacturer]
    from Products2.dbo.sourceexport source
    left join Products2.dbo.uniqueprods u 
    on source.[Manufacturer]=u.mfg
    where u.mfg is null;

    select [Manufacturer] from Products2.dbo.sourceexport where [Manufacturer]='XYZ';

    select mfg from Products2.dbo.uniqueprods where mfg='XYZ'
```

The select/join statement returns about 20 rows, The first row is 'XYZ', though it could also be of format 'XYZ             ' for some of the rows. When I copy the result (with/without padding, with/without `ltrim(rtrim(u.mfg))` on all my fields) into the second and third where statements, I am getting 15 and 260 results, respectively.

Any results from a left outer join should return 0 rows for the right table, and 260 is more than the 0 I was expecting.

Edit: I have been told in previous questions that I am too verbose. Apparently here, I am not verbose enough. Thank you. 
I want a left outer join. Meaning, I want the manufacturers in `source` that are not present in `u`. We could return all fields of all rows, if that helps you to answer the question better, and then I could create a second step to select distinct manufacturer from those results.

I have a few million records, containing information that my client considers sensitive. It would not be appropriate to allude to the industry of the manufacturer of these widgets. Neither is it particularly interesting to anyone but my client.

I have table `source` with values (a,b,c,d,f,h,j,l), and table `u` with values (a,c,e,g,g,i,k,l). I want to return values (b,d,f,h,j). I am getting return values that have a but not c in them. I don't know if it contains all of (b,d,f,h,j), because I am not confident that my statement works.

To state the question differently: how can I write a left outer join where none of the results of the statement are in the right table?

Edit2: from statements below, it appears that the syntax isn't bad. Making my first edit question restatement invalid. Going back to the original question statement, why does my left outer join return values that are found in both tables?

Other than non-visible characters (that should be solved by ltrim(rtim()), right?) and the field type, what other factors might cause the join to malfunction?

Comment: Add sample table data, current result and expected result!

Comment: Although your question was not very clear, so do you want rows that exist in sourceexport but not in uniqueproducts? Also, you have a distinct clause in your join query but not in your second & third where statements. That might give different count of rows. Rest as @jarlh mentioned, please add some more information.

Comment: @AkankshaSingh  Thank you. This is my first SQL question. VBA, for example, requests that there be much less information, and I was writing as I was accustomed to for that audience. And yes, there is a distinct clause. Row counts are irrelevant, but for one thing: the only reason that I included row counts, was because any results from the first statement, I thought, should return 0 rows for the third statement. Anything except 0 is undesirable. I probably should have just said that the row count was nonzero.

Comment: The statement you're currently using should work as an exclusion join (`LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` is pretty standard).  I suspect your columns differ in some fashion (say, `CHAR` vs `VARCHAR`, or collation or somesuch), and the data is being converted one way in one set of statements, and not/differently in the other.  What are the column definitions, and a problematic value (from each table)?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thank you. All columns in source are varchar(50), and all columns in unique are varchar(50) except for one int. I think we are getting closer to my problem, because I am not completely sure that the padded spaces (don't show up in my question) don't have something to do with this. Unfortunately, I am bound by agreements to not even post the manufacturer abbreviations here, but they are all made up of visible ASCII characters, and while some of those entries do in fact have punctuation in them, only one of the 23 'problematic values' has a non-letter visible character, `-`

Comment: If the key of Left Join i.e. manufacturer is a varchar, there is a good possibility that the data itself is not matching in many cases and LEFT join is working fine for given data. Say, if Manufacturers are strings with more than 1 word, even a single extra space can play a role in this malfunction. You have to dig deep to verify your data.

Comment: @AkankshaSingh I do have to dig deep. Thank you. What am I digging for? Other than nonvisible ASCII characters and dataype mismatch, what could cause the problem? Yes, you are right that extra spaces in the middle of the string would cause a problem, but then how does my third select statement above find results in the right table, when I copy directly from the results of the first statement. And by the way, `XYZ` is representative. Three character long strings are common in the data, and showing up as 'problematic results'

Comment: You didn't mention collation, which is an additional parameter/setting.  Another possibility is out of date statistics, I think (I thought I saw something about it affecting results once on here, but can't find that now).  Note that pretty much all string comparisons are implicitly right-trimmed, so trailing spaces are unlikely to be the culprit.  Being able to eliminate character-based problems is why numeric join columns are often used, although this isn't always possible.  Also, flip the condition around (`INNER JOIN`) and investigate why those entries are included.

Comment: Thank you. Edits trying to please various people brought us away from the point, and now this is buried... so I doubt anyone will see this. I will likely just delete it in a week or so. My problem was that the import/export tool for SQL Server Express *added* nonvisible ASCII characters that `ltrim(rtrim` *didn't trim*, which were not in the original text file. Also, I didn't understand `ltrim(rtrim(` to only take care of `asc(30)` and not the rest, so my bad there. Suggestions on how to read in flat files of various delimiters without the shipped tool are appreciated, but out of scope here.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your 2nd and 3rd sql statements are not what you think they are and you need to wrap your initial query using an In clause.
declare @t1 as table (manufacturer varchar(1))
declare @t2 as table (mfg varchar(1))

```
insert into @t1 values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('f'),('h'),('j'),('l')
insert into @t2 values ('a'),('c'),('c'),('g'),('g'),('i'),('k'),('l')
/*query 1*/
    select * 
    from @t1
    where   manufacturer in(
    select distinct source.[Manufacturer]
        from @t1 source
        left join @t2 u 
        on source.[Manufacturer]=u.mfg
        where u.mfg is null
    )
/*Query 2*/    
    select * 
    from @t2
    where   mfg in(
    select distinct source.[Manufacturer]
        from @t1 source
        left join @t2 u 
        on source.[Manufacturer]=u.mfg
        where u.mfg is null
    )
```

Query 1 now returns all values from @t1 and Query 2 returns no values.

Comment: Thank you. I suspect that my 2nd and 3rd queries are debugging statements only, and hold absolutely no use in production. I assume that these statements were only ever created for proving that the first statement wasn't working as expected, because proof is important in a forum like this. I expect that these statements will be deleted as soon as I get the left outer join to work properly.

Comment: And thank you for typing it out. As I am sure you expected, query1 works correctly for the above data. And it returns the problem values in my live data. So obviously the error must be in my data, and not in my statement.